# Upgrading JIRA 5.0.1 to JIRA 6

Tags: mysql, tomcat, java, jira, tomcat7

I am trying to upgrade my jira version from 5.1 to 6 in my test server. with windows(64) platform. So I downloaded jira 6 version with folder name as "atlassian-jira-6.0-m08-standalone". then I strated jira with in command prompt bin> start-jira.bat /fg it throws the below error. Please help me fix the error.

Error: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.getDomain()Ljava/lang/String;

Comment: Could you post the entire output? Or, at least, the stack trace?

Comment: Using JIRA_HOME:       D:\JIRA\atlassian-jira-6.0-m08-standalone
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "D:\JIRA\atlassian-jira-6.0-m08-standalone"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "D:\JIRA\atlassian-jira-6.0-m08-standalone"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "D:\JIRA\atlassian-jira-6.0-m08-standalone\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "D:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.7.0"
Using CLASSPATH:       "D:\JIRA\atlassian-jira-6.0-m08-standalone\bin\bootstrap.jar;D:\JIRA\atlassian-jira-6.0-m08-standalone\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Mar 22, 2013 7:31:47 PM

Comment: org.apache.catalina.startup.SetAllPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetAllPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Connector} Setting property 'maxSpareThreads' to '75' did not find a matching property.
Mar 22, 2013 7:31:47 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'useHttpOnly' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
Mar 22, 2013 7:31:47 PM

Comment: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.getDomain()Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.createObjectName(AbstractProtocol.java:361)

Comment: Can you add to the question the last lines of catalina.out file?

Comment: Looks like there are some settings for Tomcat6 being used for the new Tomcat 7?